# Why is $n+j-i$ a even number?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk, actuarial-science

[image]
Basically it says that for this binomial probability for the simple random walk, that the number of steps made in the upward direction, i.e. by $+1$ is $u = 0.5(n+j-i)$ why is that this value is always a non-negative even number?

Comment: Please do not post images of text, instead of the text itself. MathJax and table formatting are available. Using images instead of them makes the post less accessible.

Comment: This is fully fleshed out in Section 3.9 of Grimmett and Stirzaker Probability and Random Processes.

Comment: If, starting at $i,$ you take $a$ steps upward, and $b$ steps downward, you end up at $i+a-b.$ If you know the total number of steps is $n,$ and you end in $j,$ you get two equations: $$a+b=n\\i+a-b=j$$ Solving, you get the above values. But $a,b$ have to be positive integers, by definition.

Comment: It's worth considering the simple case where $i=j=0.$ To start at $0$ and end at $0,$ you have to take as many steps up as down, so the total steps, $n=n+0-0,$ must be even.

Comment: I can implicitly see that it is even given your case that $n$ must be even, but is there some $n = 2k$ or must I just accept that it is based on definitions?

Comment: @AndrewZhang No it isn't they don't talk about this I just viewed it.